# actionscript3 to do something if null text field is found

Tags: actionscript-3

In actionscript i have multiple dynamic text fields who are loading values from a php page using print.

```
...
vartxt1.text = receiveVars.phpVar1;
vartxt2.text = receiveVars.phpVar2;
vartxt3.text = receiveVars.phpVar3;
vartxt4.text = receiveVars.phpVar4;
vartxt5.text = receiveVars.phpVar5;
...
```

which is going very well.

Question: What i'm trying to do is, if let's say the vartxt2 is empty or has a specific value, the text field to be deleted, and the following text fields to be moved up in the place of the one deleted. The text field are one under other.

Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand, can you put an example with values? Thanks.

Comment: http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/329/khk.png  like this to be the final output ... practically ffff is going up because the eee... does not exist and a value of zero exists.

Comment: So, basically, you must put in the `TextField_X` the value of `TextField_X+1` **if** the text of `TextField_X = 0`? And the value of `TextField_X+1` keeps the same value?

Comment: i guess that like in php something like if (vartxt1.txt === 0) { print vartxt1.txt; } elseif { print vartxt2.txt; } elseif { print vartxt3.text} ... some sort of type that they all go up one step... dont't know if i explained well

Comment: In actioncscript you can do all this, please this [swf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fj03fu7p3gs4sc/FlexUtils.swf), you can run this on the browser. Check if is useful, and then i post a code with a little explanation.

Comment: hmm... now that im thinking what i want is that if (vartxt1.text === 0) { move vartxt2-5 up 10px}, if (vartxt2.text === 0) move vartxt3-5 up 10px .... an so forth .... how do i do that in actionscript??? thank you   ----LATER: seen the swf, working well except that the original fffff must be deleted, with all the textfield...

Comment: Please first see the link I sent you, and tell me if its ok, or the last control should dissapear.

Comment: Well here's what you need [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fj03fu7p3gs4sc/FlexUtils.swf), in this swf, the TextInput are removed. Tell me if that was useful.

Comment: yeap great job :D that's the function i want.... could you provide the code as an answer to mark as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.TextInput;

            private var txtArr:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
            private var size:int;

            public function init():void{
                var arr:Array = ["aaaaaaa","bbbbbbbb","ccccccc","ddddddddddd","0","ffffffff","eeeeeee","0","ggggg","hhhhhh"];
                var i:int = 0;
                for each(var obj:String in arr){
                    var txt:TextInput = new TextInput();
                    txt.text = obj;
                    txt.id = "txt" + i.toString();
                    txtArr[i] = txt;
                    addChild(txt);
                    i++;
                }
                size = i;
            }

            public function sort():void{
                for(var i:int; i < size - 1; i++){
                    var str:String = TextInput(txtArr[i]).text;
                    if(str==null || str.length==0 || str=="0"){
                        TextInput(txtArr[i]).text = TextInput(txtArr[i + 1]).text;  
                        removeChild(txtArr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button id="btn" label="Click Me" click="sort()"/>
</mx:Application>
```

I hope will be useful. You can dowload the Flex Project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kc6a2v97g1h910/FlexUtils.fxp).

Comment: uhhh.. so complicated... i have some time now to figure out how to include in my simple project...:) thank you very much, for the answer

Comment: Thanks, do not worry for the code, is very simple, in txtArr you must put the TextInput controls, the sorting process is done in the **sort** function. The **init** function is only for recreate an example like yours.